# C++ What's wrong with my bytes array to int and int to byte array converters?

Tags: c++, int, byte

i know there is a lot of questions about it, but most of them uses fixed sized converters, like 4 bytes to int and etc.
I have an templated functions to convert bytes to numbers and etc, but have a problem :D

```
template <typename IntegerType>
     static IntegerType bitsToInt(BYTE* bits, bool little_endian = true)
     {
         IntegerType result = 0;

         if (little_endian)
             for (int n = sizeof(IntegerType); n >= 0; n--)
                 result = (result << 8) + bits[n];
         else
             for (int n = 0; n < sizeof(IntegerType); n++)
                 result = (result << 8) + bits[n];

         return result;
     }

     template <typename IntegerType>
     static BYTE *intToBits(IntegerType value)
     {
         BYTE result[sizeof(IntegerType)] = { 0 };

         for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(IntegerType); i++)
             result = (value >> (i * 8));

         return result;
     }

     static void TestConverters()
     {
         short int test = 12345;

         BYTE *bytes = intToBits<short int>(test);

         short int test2 = bitsToInt<short int>(bytes); //<--i getting here different number, then 12345, so something goes wrong at conversion
     }
```

So, could anyone say what's wrong here?

Comment: I haven't checked the whole thing, but for (int n = sizeof(IntegerType); n >= 0; n--) 
 should probably read as for (int n = sizeof(IntegerType)-1; n >= 0; n--)

Comment: What compiler are you using? `result = (value >> (i * 8));` should not even compile. Also you should try enabling warnings...

Comment: and how does intToBits compile, when it's trying to assign a new value to the constant pointer 'result' ? shouldn't it be result[i] = ... ?

Comment: i am using vc++ 2010 express and it compiles fine :P

Comment: looks like it's full of bugs :(

Comment: not sure about sizeof(IntegerType) - 1, but after using new to allocate memory in intToBits and using result[i] = 0xFF & (value >> (i * 8)); i getting same number after conversion :P Thanks to everyone

Comment: for your little endian path, without the -1 i suggested, your first loop iteration reads bits[4] (for a 4 byte integer). But only indices 0-3 are valid. You will 'get away with this' if bits[4] happens to contain 0.

Comment: aww, you are right about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bugs in the function intsToBits
1. Insted of

```
result = (value >> (i * 8));
```

there should be

```
result[i] = 0xFF & (value >> (i * 8));
```

More serious one you return the pointer to the memory on the stack, which is generally incorrect after you exit the function. You shoul allocate the memory with the `new` operator.

```
BYTE * result = new BYTE[sizeof(IntegerType)];
```

The you'll be needed to release the memory

Comment: one more thing, now i need to use delete to free memory, but i can't use it in intToBits, because there is nothing to return then. is it correct to use delete bytes; at the end of TestConverners?

Comment: @Kosmos: Yes it is "correct" to `delete` it there, but it is a bad practice to allocate something in a function and to force the user to care for it. Mainly because the user **must** know how you allocated the memory in the first place. It would probably better to either return a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr`) or a `std::vector` (by value).

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i wanted to know about bad practice :P i think i will use vector for that. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
static BYTE *intToBits(IntegerType value)
```

This is returning a pointer to locally allocated memory, which once the function returns goes out of scope and is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your only problem, but intToBits is returning a pointer to a local variable, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `new` to allocate the byte array you return